# Setting a View's background color

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicolor

I created a custom color and want to set it as my views color. In my views ViewController in the viewDidLoad method I put `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.jLimeColor()`. It doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Custom Color

    `extension UIColor
    {
        class func jLimeColor () -> UIColor
        {
            return UIColor(red: 98, green: 255, blue: 130, alpha: 1)
        }
    }`

Comment: How did you create a custom color?

Comment: It's not that because I tried with the built in colors too but I will post the code.

Comment: You need to divide your color numbers by 255.0 because it expects a number between 0 and 1. See if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a custom view on top of the main "View". When I set the color the main "View" underneath was being set. I just had to make an outlet to the view or set it manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want this custom color in one single ViewController, you can just write the function in the Class.

```
func customColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

If you gonna use this kind of color for `Global Hierarchy`, then you can create a `CustomColor Class`.

```
import UIKit

public let CustomColor1 = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
public let CustomColor2 = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
public let CustomColor3 = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: The problem isn't the custom color but the setting of it. I have tried with the built in UIColors and it still doesn't work but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Did you use a custom view in your ViewController?

Comment: Yes I did now that you mention it!

Comment: If you used a custom View, I think you can not just write `self.view.backgroundColor` before claim `self.view = customView`. And the sure thing is you shall create the instance of the `CustomView` firstly.